# Close Date FQ = Created Date FQ

Tags: reporting

I'm creating an opportunity report and need to show all opportunities closed between January1- March 31 and opp crated Date is also within the same Fiscal Quarter
HELP!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed from the report editor it looks like you can only query relative dates for 1 date field at a time.

BUT! You can also do that in additional filter fields, using relative date values. I've created an example in this screenshot:

[image]

Of course you can create a lot of variations on this scenario. E.g. putting both fields as filters will give you a report that is always relative to today.
If you need absolute days (always Q1 2014) you can't use the relative filters but can add 2 criteria for CreatedDate:

[image]

The full list of relative date criteria that can be used this way can be found here:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=custom_dates.htm&language=en_US